# Wordpress password protection - PHP who's logged in?

Tags: wordpress, password-protection

Im using 2.8 Wordpress's generic password protection on my pages with the [Password Protected Child Pages Plugin](http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/password-protect-children-pages) and I'm also including PHP files on the protected child pages, but I'd like to figure out what PHP code I need to see if they are viewing the page from entering password "A" or entering password "B"

Is this even possiable??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I used the is_page() function to assigin a variable... not the best solution because I'll have to add any new page to the php file that checks to see which pages go to each password, but its all I could come up with.